# htaccess 301 redirect with URL rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I would need some expert advice on how to make a proper 301 URL redirect using htaccess. I already have a rewrite rule and need to also add a redirect. This is the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^results/(case1|case2|case3)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /results.php?v1=$1&v2=$2&v3=$3&v4=$4&v5=$5&v6=$6&v7=$7 [L]
```

What should I add in the rule above to make a successful redirect from:

```
http://www.website.com/results.php?v1=case2&v2=a&v3=b&v4=c&v5=d&v6=e&v7=f
to:
http://www.website.com/results/case2/a/b/c/d/e/f/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional rule to redirect your url,  add the following bellow `RewriteEngine on` line :

```
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /results\.php\?v1=(case1|case2|case3)&v2=([^&]+)&v3=([^&]+)&v4=([^&]+)&v5=([^&]+)&v6=([^&]+)&v7=([^&\s]+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /results/%1/%2/%3/%4/%5/%6/%7? [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, I haven't tested this yet - how can this be made to account for the `(case1|case2|case3)` in the redirect rule? I have other urls that contain for example `case4` and `case5`. Those will redirect to different url.

Comment: I just tested your solution, the url is redirected but I get this at the end - `%20HTTP/1.1/`. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: ahh, I cleared the cache and it worked! Thank you very much for bearing with me to find the right solution!